# Populate select with javascript array

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, drop-down-menu

I have two selects in my form : sources and files, everytime a source is chosen , I want to add the source chosen's files in the second select which is for the files
So far I made this:

```
     <div class="form-group">
<label>Select source(s)</label> <br>
<select class="selectpicker" multiple name="source" onchange="getval(this);">
<c:forEach var="source" items="${sources}">
<option value="${source.source_id}">${source.url}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>

</div>

 <div class="form-group">
  <label>Select file(s)</label> <br>
 <select class="selectpicker" multiple id="file" name="file">

  </select>

  </div>
```

and this is the getVal() function:

```
 function getval()
 { 
 var myList = new Array();

 <c:forEach items="${files}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
    myList["${loop.index}"] = "${item.description}";

     </c:forEach>
    var select = document.getElementById("file");
    for(index in myList) {
   var opt = document.createElement('option');
     option.text =myList[index];
    select.add(option);
    }

  }
```

Comment: You are missing the line where you create an "option" element. Also, pls specify what error you are getting.

Comment: I've added this line" var opt = document.createElement('option');" but still the second select is empty after I select from the first one

Comment: See my ans. You need not use JSP in getVal at all.

Answer (score 0):

JSP runs on the server side and the javascript on the client side.

JSP requires a form submit or page reload to act , whereas the effect you want can best be done using javascript, which is run on the client's browser, without interaction with the server.

Use javascript, not JSP for the getVal function; it is fine to use JSP for the initial values of the source dropdown though.

Do also give an id attribute to your "source" select:

```
function getval()
{ 
    var opts = document.getElementById("source").options;
    var select = document.getElementById("file");
    // remove previous options in 
    for( index in select.options)
       select.remove( index );
    for( index in opts ) {
         if( opts[index].selected )
         {
               var option = document.createElement("option");
               option.value = opts[index].value ;
               option.text = opts[index].text ;
               select.add(option);
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: I have to use jsp to get the list of files from the servlet

Comment: from what I understood what your function does is get the options of the sources select to the files select and that's not what I want , what I want is to populate the files select with the all files of  all the selected sources , for now I want to populate it with all the files existant in my database as a first step then I will test if the id of the file equals the value of the option of the select source I'm iterating over. hope that clears up my idea

Comment: Ok, but please then explain what the error is, are the selects not showing up?

Comment: the files select is empty

Comment: As an aside, try evoking getval() on files select menu's onload as well. If that doesn't work, try seeing generated source via 'Inspect Element' in Dev Tools.

Comment: could you please tell me how to evoke it onload ?

Comment: <select class="selectpicker" multiple id="file" name="file" onload="getval()">

  </select>

Comment: Use Inspect Element' in Dev Tools to see if your script is being generated the way you want it to. I think it isn't.